# org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch refentCodifStdId

Tags: avro

I'm using this avsc content:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "ReferentialMessageType",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "type",
    "type" : "string"
  }, 
  {
    "name" : "dictionnaire",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "dictionnaireType",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "refentDictId",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictCode",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictLibelleCrt",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictLibelleLng",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictDateFin",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        } ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictPere",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictDateDbt",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        } ],
        "default" : null
      } ]
    } ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "codification",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "codificationType",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdId",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentDictId",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdCode",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdRng",
        "type" : [ "null", "double" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdLibCrt",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdLibLng",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdDateDbt",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        } ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdDateFin",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        } ],
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "refentCodifStdPere",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      } ]
    } ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

and trying to publish this message on kafka:

{
"type":"insert",
"dictionnaire":null,
"codification":{
"refentCodifStdId":"8",
"refentDictId":"2",
"refentCodifStdCode":"AAAA",
"refentCodifStdLibCrt":"BBBB",
"refentCodifStdPere":"2"
}
}

But I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch refentCodifStdId
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:434)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.akhq.modules.AvroSerializer.fromJsonToAvro(AvroSerializer.java:63)
    at org.akhq.modules.AvroSerializer.toAvro(AvroSerializer.java:48)
    at org.akhq.repositories.RecordRepository.produce(RecordRepository.java:528)
    at org.akhq.controllers.TopicController.produce(TopicController.java:141)
    at org.akhq.controllers.$TopicControllerDefinition$$exec4.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please help to understand what is wrong ?

Regards

Comment: I'm guessing the issue exists somewhere in `org.akhq.modules.AvroSerializer.fromJsonToAvro` because JSON does not have a 1:1 mapping for Avro union types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a JSON like below so that the type is explicitly called out for the union fields:

```json
{
  "type": "insert",
  "dictionnaire": null,
  "codification": {
    "codificationType": {
        "refentCodifStdId": {
            "string": "8"
        },
        "refentDictId":  {
            "string": "2"
        },
        "refentCodifStdCode":  {
            "string": "AAAA"
        },
        "refentCodifStdLibCrt": {
            "string": "BBBB"
        },
        "refentCodifStdPere": {
            "string": "2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had to modify the json with explicit type for each element. Thanks